# Python enumerated array syntax

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm writing in Python and writing to a console with an array I am manipulating and have a syntax question.

The array is passed in and I create another another array for tracking position using along with sort the array but I dont see why when I want to access the iterable array it becomes a 2d array

```
posarr = [*enumerate(arr)]
posarr.sort(key = lambda it:it[1])
```

Then to access from a loop it is:

```
posarr[i][0] == blah
```

instead of

```
posarr[i] == blah
```

?

Comment: posarr is an array of two elements, position and data.

Comment: `posarr = posarr.sort(key = lambda it:it[1])` is wrong, because `posarr.sort` does sorting in place and returns `None`.

Comment: @ChrisCharley Can you tell me the reas

Comment: If you want just the original positions of the sorted elements, you can use `[i for i, x in sorted(enumerate(arr), key=lambda it: it[1])]` or just `sorted(range(len(arr)), key=arr.__getitem__)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a 2D array, it's a list of tuples. In each tuple, the first item is the index, and the second is the value (as you would expect from [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate)).

Forget about the sorting for now, just look at what `posarr` contains, for example:

```
>>> posarr = [*enumerate('cab')]
>>> posarr
[(0, 'c'), (1, 'a'), (2, 'b')]
```

BTW this has nothing to do with syntax.

Answer (score 0):

Note: **The `enumerate()` function assigns an index to each item in an iterable object**

So, `posarr = [*enumerate(arr)]` will create a new *array of tuples*, where the first item of the tuple will be the *index* and the second item be the array *element* at that index.

After `posarr = posarr.sort(key = lambda it:it[1])`, `posarr` will be `None` because `list.sort()` does not return anything. It sorts an array *in-place*.
It should be like this: `posarr.sort(key = lambda it:it[1])`.

`posarr[i]` will return the *tuple* at index `i`, so to access the element at that index, you have to do something like this `posarr[i][1]`. `posarr[i][0]` is the index of the element `posarr[i][1]`.

So, `posarr` is not a *2-D array*, it is just an array of *tuples*.